# How to make the selected dropdown value to display on the header on change using angular2 and typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have a dropdown field, if i click on car, it must display "car" beside the heading using angular2. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Html:

```
<h1>Heading <span *ngFor= "let apps of apps">({{apps.name}})</span></h1>
       <div class="form-group">
        <select class="box">
         <option *ngFor= "let apps of apps" >{{apps.name}}</option>
        </select>  
        </div>
```

ts:

```
this.apps = [
        { "name": "car" },
        { "name": "bike" }
   ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h1> Heading {{appName}}</h1>
<select type="number" [(ngModel)]="appName" >
  <option *ngFor="let app of apps" [ngValue]="app.name">{{app.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Check this [Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/ivE7c8ykiHG7TK1Hfr0Q/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but here i want car to be prefilled, after updating your code, its not getting prefilled.. can u help me

Comment: yeah sure. gimme a sec

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, I've attached a plunker. Hope this will be helpful enough

Answer (score 1):

PFB the TS change

```
    export class AppComponent  {

      apps:any;
      selectedApp : any;
      constructor(){
this.selectedApp=car;
      this.apps = [
            { "name": "car" },
            { "name": "bike" }
       ];
      }
    }
```

PFB the HTML change

```
<p>
      {{selectedApp}}
    </p>
    <select class="box" [(ngModel)]="selectedApp">
             <option *ngFor= "let app of apps" [value]="app.name">{{app.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: SelectedApp is set as car to prefill with car value, you can change to other values too